Mount kubernetes volume as non-root user
I am trying to deploy Django project on k3s. I build my image to run as user app:
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11-slim AS builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install python dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11-slim

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup --system app && adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "3", "myapp.wsgi"]

I want to mount static files folder to persistant volume. But when I start deployment folder /home/app/web/static belongs to root:root. What am I doing wrong?
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deploy
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        type: backend
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 100
        runAsGroup: 101
        fsGroup: 2000
      volumes:
        - name: staticfiles
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: static-pvc
      containers:
        - name: backend-pod
          image: myapp-backend-arm64:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: backend-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: backend-cm
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/home/app/web/static"
              name: staticfiles
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
      type: backend

app@backend-deploy-7595c5d447-z9ztz:~/web$ id
uid=100(app) gid=101(app) groups=101(app),2000
app@backend-deploy-7595c5d447-z9ztz:~/web$ ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 1 app  app  4096 Sep 26 16:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Sep 25 20:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 app  app  1375 Sep 26 15:54 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 app  app   662 Sep 25 19:07 manage.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 app  app    58 Sep 25 19:07 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 app  app  4096 Sep 26 17:06 myapp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Sep 26 14:11 static

UPDATE
The problem was the permissions on the host.

You can try using the init container with the same volume mount and change the permissions as you required. In your case changing to non root user. You can add init container like shown below (change as per your requirement)
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deploy
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        type: backend
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 100
        runAsGroup: 101
        fsGroup: 2000
      volumes:
        - name: staticfiles
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: static-pvc
      containers:
        - name: backend-pod
          image: myapp-backend-arm64:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: backend-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: backend-cm
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /home/app/web/static
              name: staticfiles
       initContainers:   #Adding init container
        - name: volume-mount-hack
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 101:101 /data/demo"] #Change the permission based on your requirement
          volumeMounts:
            - name: staticfiles
              mountPath: /home/app/web/static

Refer to SO question to know more about how to mount volume as a non root user.
Refer to this official k8 init containers to know more about usage of init containers.

I've read about that, and I got an idea that it is an outdated solution and everyone recommends using securityContext instead. But for some reason it doesn't work for me. And that's what I am trying to figure out.
